# This Javascript Filter Function Searches Through HTML Characters

Tags: javascript, html

This function is from w3school's W3.js.

This function is supposed to filter a list of items by typing in a search box.
For some reason, this includes html in the search instead of only the text in the innerHTML.

E.g. A search for `<td>` will return all the rows. How do I make this use only text within the elements?

```js
"use strict";
var w3 = {};
w3.getElements = function (id) {
  if (typeof id == "object") {
    return [id];
  } else {
    return document.querySelectorAll(id);
  }
};

w3.filterHTML = function(id, sel, filter) {
  var a, b, c, i, ii, iii, hit;
  a = w3.getElements(id);
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b = w3.getElements(sel);
    for (ii = 0; ii < b.length; ii++) {
      hit = 0;
      if (b[ii].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
        hit = 1;
      }
      c = b[ii].getElementsByTagName("*");
      for (iii = 0; iii < c.length; iii++) {
        if (c[iii].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
          hit = 1;
        }
      }
      if (hit == 1) {
        b[ii].style.display = "";
      } else {
        b[ii].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<input oninput="w3.filterHTML('#id01', '.item', this.value)" placeholder="Search for names..">

<table id="id01" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>Berlin</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Luleå</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>México D.F.</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You could try using jQuery and replacing `.innerHTML` with `.text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) instead of `innerHTML` is a simple way around this. Although this was originally only in Internet Explorer, it is now in all major browsers and part of the HTML DOM standard.

```js
"use strict";
var w3 = {};
w3.getElements = function (id) {
  if (typeof id == "object") {
    return [id];
  } else {
    return document.querySelectorAll(id);
  }
};

w3.filterHTML = function(id, sel, filter) {
  var a, b, c, i, ii, iii, hit;
  a = w3.getElements(id);
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b = w3.getElements(sel);
    for (ii = 0; ii < b.length; ii++) {
      hit = 0;
      if (b[ii].innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
        hit = 1;
      }
      c = b[ii].getElementsByTagName("*");
      for (iii = 0; iii < c.length; iii++) {
        if (c[iii].innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
          hit = 1;
        }
      }
      if (hit == 1) {
        b[ii].style.display = "";
      } else {
        b[ii].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<input oninput="w3.filterHTML('#id01', '.item', this.value)" placeholder="Search for names..">

<table id="id01" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>Berlin</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Luleå</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>México D.F.</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Would you know how I can exclude <script> tags from the search? I have javascript in my rows whose content is interfering with the search.